# Ошибка чтения json файла в libGDX

Tags: json, libgdx

Пытаюсь реализовать Dialog из libGDX.При чтении файла json Для Skin появляется ошибка

> Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: white

В проект я добавил uiskin.atlas, default.fnt, uiskin.png.

Код uiskin.json:

```
{
  BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },
  Color: {
    green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
    white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
    red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
    black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 },
  },
  TintedDrawable: {
    dialogDim: { name: white, color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0.45 } },
  },
  ButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round },
    toggle: { parent: default, checked: default-round-down }
  },
  TextButtonStyle: {
    default: { parent: default, font: default-font, fontColor: white },
    toggle: { parent: default, checked: default-round-down, downFontColor: red }
  },
  ScrollPaneStyle: {
    default: { vScroll: default-scroll, hScrollKnob: default-round-large, background: default-rect, hScroll: default-scroll, vScrollKnob: default-round-large }
  },
  SelectBoxStyle: {
    default: {
      font: default-font, fontColor: white, background: default-select,
      scrollStyle: default,
      listStyle: { font: default-font, selection: default-select-selection }
    }
  },
  SplitPaneStyle: {
    default-vertical: { handle: default-splitpane-vertical },
    default-horizontal: { handle: default-splitpane }
  },
  WindowStyle: {
    default: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white },
    dialog: { parent: default, stageBackground: dialogDim }
  },
  ProgressBarStyle: {
    default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob },
    default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-round-large }
  },
  SliderStyle: {
    default-horizontal: { parent: default-horizontal },
    default-vertical: { parent: default-vertical }
  },
  LabelStyle: {
    default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }
  },
  TextFieldStyle: {
    default: { selection: selection, background: textfield, font: default-font, fontColor: white, cursor: cursor }
  },
  CheckBoxStyle: {
    default: { checkboxOn: check-on, checkboxOff: check-off, font: default-font, fontColor: white }
  },
  ListStyle: {
    default: { fontColorUnselected: white, selection: selection, fontColorSelected: white, font: default-font }
  },
  TouchpadStyle: {
    default: { background: default-pane, knob: default-round-large }
  },
  TreeStyle: {
    default: { minus: tree-minus, plus: tree-plus, selection: default-select-selection }
  },
  TextTooltipStyle: {
    default: {
      label: { font: default-font, fontColor: white },
      background: default-pane, wrapWidth: 150
    }
  },
}
```

Все эти файлы я брал с https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data

Comment: Вообще, это не json. Потому что в json имена и значения должны быть в кавычках.

Comment: Вероятно, это какой-то диалект формата, наподобие json5. Соответственно, нужен парсер, понимающий именно этот формат.

Comment: Хотя, судя по ошибке, парсер понимает формат. Значит дело не в этом. Что-то где-то не зарегистрировано.